# Unpacking a list inside a function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 ggplot objects in a list called `main_type_plots` and I want to combine them with `ggarrange`. I have the following piece of code which works fine:

```
ggarrange(main_type_plots[[1]],
          main_type_plots[[2]], 
          main_type_plots[[3]], 
          main_type_plots[[4]], 
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

but looks absolutely terrible...

I was wondering if there is a trick that makes it look prettier?

---

Thanks to @markus and @Brian, you can do either:

```
patchwork::wrap_plots(main_type_plots, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

or

```
ggarrange(plotlist = main_type_plots)
```

Comment: Have you tried `do.call(ggarrange, c(list(main_type_plots), list(ncol = 2, nrow = 2)))` ?

Comment: Yes, it says: `cannot convert object of class list into a grob.`

Comment: Try `patchwork::wrap_plots(main_type_plots)`

Comment: ?ggarrange will show you the optional argument `plotlist =`, where you can pass in your list `main_type_plots`.